Assigning the same register multiple times in the same always block but with different conditions
I have a question.
so I know that in this code:
reg a;

always @(posedge clk) begin

    if (enable1) begin
      a <= 0;
    end
    if (enable2) begin
      a <= 1;
    end
end

enable2 gets priority, because it is further down, so a=1.
but what if the code looked like this:
reg a;
reg state<=0;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    
    a=0;

    case(state) 
    0: begin
    if (enable) begin
      a=1; end
    end
end

Is a=1 still? does'nt it has to pass more logic gates? Or will it always take priority because of the code, and synthesization will take care of it?
Thanks!

Within a single procedural always process, statements execute in order, last write always wins. Synthesis analyzes your code and gives priority to the conditions that would cause that last write to happen.
SystemVerilog does have a unique if and unique case construct that makes an assertion that only one condition can happen; then synthesis is free to optimize the logic in parallel.
always @(posedge clk) begin

    unique if (enable1) begin
      a <= 0;
    end
    else if (enable2) begin
      a <= 1;
    end
    else
      a< = 'x; // don't care
end

